# Every integers divisible by $1$ but is $1$ the factor of all the integers?

Tags: arithmetic

The question looks so silly but anyway I have to ask. We know that every integer is divisible by $1$ but can we say that $1$ is a factor of every integer? Because $1$ is a unit of integers.

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor#General)

Comment: The answer can yourself to have looking careful  at the (mathematical) definition of divisibility and of factor. (Some trouble could appears seen the involve definition of irreducibility but this is not question here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $1$ is a factor of every integer. It is said not to be a *proper* factor (the proper factors are those that differ from $1$ and the number itself).

Beware anyway that it is not a prime factor and will not appear in the prime factorization.

Example:

$$60=2^2\cdot3\cdot5$$ has the factors $$\color{red}1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12, 15,20,30,\color{red}{60}.$$